How to prevent / delete rmeta files from rustc --crate-type lib
Problem Description
I've run into this problem while trying to build a library with rust on windows. Basically every time I run the rustc src/lib.rs --crate-type lib command (to build the library), it creates an new undeletable folder in the root directory.
Things I've tried:

Trying to change the permissions of the folder gives a You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.
Trying to delete the folders normally gives a You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this folder (even if I am administrator).
Trying to use WSL to see the permissions on the folders gives the following output.

COMPUTERNAME:/path/to/files$ ls -la
ls: ./rmetav34fQE: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetaQoN7tZ: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetalnhtFb: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetapLSIJu: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetalAhWCV: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetay2oX6j: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmeta5PoZrb: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetaynngfa: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetaXdgJbr: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetalxpcGH: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetavvYhBF: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetaV5MmHj: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetatO66wd: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetaAzjiVn: No such file or directory
ls: ./rmetatl9WSy: No such file or directory
total 640
drwxrwxrwx    1 username username       512 Apr 30 23:31 .
drwxrwxrwx    1 username username       512 Jun 20  2023 ..
drwxrwxrwx    1 username username       512 Apr 30 23:32 .git
-rwxrwxrwx    1 username username        28 May  1 01:46 .gitignore
-rwxrwxrwx    1 username username       153 Apr 30 23:58 Cargo.lock
-rwxrwxrwx    1 username username       178 Apr 30 23:58 Cargo.toml
-rwxrwxrwx    1 username username        16 Apr 30 23:34 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx    1 username username     90406 May  1 02:01 liblib.rlib
drwxrwxrwx    1 username username       512 Apr 30 23:33 src
drwxrwxrwx    1 username username       512 Apr 30 23:35 target

Questions
What are some args I can use to at least move this output somewhere else (like in the build folder) and is there any way to delete these annoying files? Also would it makes sense to open an issue in the rustc repository for this as this doesn't seem exactly intentional?
The files exist on a 1TB exFAT formatted external SSD if that makes a difference.

You should not use rustc directly.

Is the folder in the root directory of the project or in the root directory on the drive (like directly inside C:\)?

In the command prompt, try icacls path\to\directory to get permissions of a folder.

Apparently the classic "unplug it and plug it back in" worked here. After remounting the drive the folders disappeared:/

@ChayimFriedman why not?? I thought this is literally recommended by the docs?

@some1and2 It is definitely not. If you think you need to use rustc directly, you are wrong. If you need to use it directly, you know it, not just think it. Use Cargo.
